# Why don't my brake lights and rear turn signals work? 2005 town and county

Tags: chrysler, turn-signal, town-and-country, brake-light

Why don't my brake lights and rear turn signals not written on my 2005 town and country. My hazards and tail lights do work.

Comment: Check for blown bulbs first, then check for blown fuses, then broken wires at the rear... and that’s the order I would take...

Comment: I did check bulbs and fuses haven't checked wires at the rear. Where should i be looking?

Comment: Did you replace the bulbs with ones you know are good?

Comment: If hazards are working then the bulbs are good for brake lights and turn signals also. More than likely a bad turn signal switch.